# Are the fibrations between $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-local objects $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-fibration?

Tags: homotopy-theory, motivic-homotopy

Let $S$ be Noetherian scheme and $(Sm/S)_{Nis}$ is the Nisnevich site of smooth schemes over $S$. The category of simplicial sheaves on $(Sm/S)_{Nis}$ is denoted 
 $Spc(S)$ and this category has two model structures. One is the usual model structure of simplicial sheaves and another is the $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-model structure. I write $Ex_{\mathbb{A}^{1}}$ for the  $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-fibrant replacement functor.

My Question

If $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ are $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-fibrant objects (i.e.,$\mathbb{A}^{1}$-local objects) in $Spc(S)$ and a morphism $f:\mathscr{Y} \longrightarrow \mathscr{X}$ is a fibration of simplicial sheaves, then is $f$ an $\mathbb{A}^{1}$-fibration ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is a general property of left Bousfield localization. A map between local objects is a fibration (i.e. in $\mathcal{M}$) if and only if it's a local fibration (i.e. fibration in $L_{\mathcal{C}}\mathcal{M}$). This is the content of Proposition 3.3.16 in Hirschhorn's book.

Comment: Thank you. It is too hard for me to read P.Hirschhorn's book Model Categories and Their Localization. As some of proofs of propositions in that book were drawn from latter, I cannot read it from the first.